# An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the DeleteBucket operation: Access Denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the DeleteBucket operation: Access Denied

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-31-84 temp]$ aws s3 rb --force s3://elasticbeanstalk-us-east-2-719330736384/
```

> remove_bucket failed: s3://elasticbeanstalk-us-east-2-719330736384/ An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the DeleteBucket operation: Access Denied

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: How do i remove bucket in s3 using awscli ?

Comment: The error message clearly says you do not have privileges to delete the bucket. Talk to your IAM administrator.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Elastic Beanstalk Bucket policies by default denies deletion.

Go to the bucket's policy (bucket --> properties --> permissions --> edit bucket policy)

Then find this statement

```
{
"Sid": xxxxxxxxx,
"Effect": "Deny",
"Principal": {
"AWS": "*"
},
"Action": "s3:DeleteBucket",
"Resource": xxxxxxxxxx
}
```

Change the Effect from *Deny* to *Allow*.

Save the change to the Bucket Policy.

Try deleting again.

Comment: Thanks for a working solution! BTW, I've used [AWS Policy Generator](http://awspolicygen.s3.amazonaws.com/policygen.html) to generate new policy and deleted, using `aws s3 rb s3://elasticbeanstalk-us-west-2-xxxxxxxxxxxx --force` command.

Comment: Thanks! This saves my day!

Answer (score 0):

The solution of @J. Prashar didn't work for me.
You just need to go to bucket --> properties --> permissions --> edit bucket policy and delete the policy.
Then, you can delete the bucket without any problem.